# AutoMapper's AssertConfigurationIsValid and EF navigation properties

Tags: unit-testing, automapper

I discovered AutoMapper's [Configuration Validation feature](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration-validation.html) today and it looks very promising. Using it I should be able to get rid of all our manually written unit tests for our AutoMapper profiles. We use AutoMapper to map between Entity Framework entity classes and View Model classes.

Imagine I have the following entity:

```
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int TypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TypeId")]
    [InverseProperty("Article")]
    public ArticleType Type { get; set; }
}
```

And the corresponding View Model:

```
public class ArticleViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int TypeId { get; set; }

    public string TypeName { get; set; }
}
```

I have left out ArticleType for brevity.

Now, in my AutoMapper profile I would have these mappings:

```
CreateMap<ArticleViewModel, Article>()

CreateMap<Article, ArticleViewModel>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.TypeName, options => options.MapFrom(src => src.Type.Name))
```

If I call `AssertConfigurationIsValid` on a `MapperConfiguration` with this profile in it AutoMapper will complain that `Type` is not mapped. That is true, but I do not need to map it since Entity Framework will automatically figure it out from the foreign key `TypeId`.

I know I can add an Ignore for `Type`, like below, to get rid of this error:

```
CreateMap<ArticleViewModel, Article>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.Type, options => options.Ignore())
```

But we have entities with a lot of navigation properties to other entities and having to ignore them all becomes tedious.

The other alternative I came up with is to use the source's members to validate the mapping, like this:

```
CreateMap<ArticleViewModel, Article>(MemberList.Source)
```

Is there a best practice for this?

Comment: You can use `ForAllMaps` and `ForAllMembers` to ignore all FKs.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu How would I do that, given that all FKs have different names?

Comment: Surely there is a pattern :)